# SQL Multiple columns

Tags: php, sql

I have this code:

```
<?php
          $get_news = $db->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE category = 1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 5");
          $array = $db->assoc($get_news);
          $num = $db->num($get_news);

          if ($num == 0) {
              echo "<div class=\"title\">No news found!</div>";
              }

           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_news)){
          ?>


               <div class="blue box">
                 <div class="title"><?php echo $array['title'];?></div>
                   <div class="content">

                    <img src="panel/_news/<?php echo $array['image'];?>" style="max-width: 150px;max-height:150px;" alt=\"\" align="center">



            <div style="margin-top: 14px;">
               <div class="readmore">By <?php echo $array['poster'];?></div>
               <div class="date"><?php echo $array['date'];?></div>

              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

and basically, I'm trying to make it show 3 news posts, but it shows the same one, do you guys know what it is that I'm doing wrong in the SQL?

This is what it shows: http://screencloud.net/v/5ENE

I have more than 3 articles in the database, but it's showing the 1 3 times.. Can you guys help?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk is right, you need to use `$row` and not `$array`. Also, use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead, as this gives you an associative array that you can refer to indexes with names, rather than numbers. `$array` contains only the first row from the result.

Comment: **Do** ***not*** use `mysql_` functions; they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing two different API's.

You need to reference `$row` not `$array`. Something like:

```
while ($row = $db->assoc($get_news)) {
?>
           <div class="blue box">
             <div class="title"><?php echo $row['title'];?></div>
<?php
}
```